# ajax auto-completion bind data to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Am getting data from ajax call, How to bind data for text box auto-completion with name and id as fields.

How to bind the data in front end and get selected name's id in back end java.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
        $("#customerName").autocomplete({     
        source : function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
                url : "/customer/getByNames",
                type : "GET",
                data : {
                        name : $("#customerName").val()
                },
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {

               response(data);
                }
        });
}
});
});
});

<input type="text" id="customerName" name="customerName"
            th:field="*{customer.name}"  />
```

JSON returned data from ajax call (Data at sucess)

```
[ 
{"id": 1,"name": "Customer_01"}, 
{"id": 2,"name": "Customer_02"}, 
{"id": 3,"name": "Customer_03"},
{"id": 4,"name": "Customer_04"} 
]
```

Need to bind name field of JSON to textbox as auto-completion

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data from your AJAX call to a method to initialize the auto complete plugin.

The method can have a name of selectors to initialize or if your selectors are in the data then you can map the data to an array of selectors you want to bind auto complete for.

```
$(document).ready(function()
        $.ajax({
                url : "/customer/getByNames",
                type : "GET",
                data : {
                        name : $("#customerName").val()
                },
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {
                    setAutoComplete(data);
                }
        });
});

function setAutoComplete(data) 
{
    var selectors = ["#someId", "someotherId"];
    //if your selector are in the data then use data.map to get your selectors.
    selectors.forEach(function(selector)
    {
        $(selector).autocomplete({
            source: data
        });
    }
}
```

If your data has a special format you can use a custom render function to initialize the auto complete plugin.

For example, this allow you to group auto complete data with a category and field into groups using this JSON set as `formModel`:

```
{
   "Contact":{
      "FirstName":"Contact.FirstName",
      "MiddleInitial":"Contact.MiddleInitial",
      "LastName":"Contact.LastName",
      "Address1":"Contact.Address1",
      "Address2":"Contact.Address2",
      "City":"Contact.City",
      "State":"Contact.State",
      "PostalCode":"Contact.PostalCode",
      "WorkPhone":"Contact.WorkPhone",
      "HomePhone":"Contact.HomePhone",
      "Email":"Contact.Email"
   },

   "UDFs":{
      "ModifiedBy":"Contact.UDFs.ModifiedBy",
      "ModifiedDate":"Contact.UDFs.ModifiedDate",
      "SessionId":"Contact.UDFs.SessionId",
      "FormData":"Contact.UDFs.FormData"
   }
}
```

I use this code:

```
function getFormModel() {
        var availableTags = [];
        for (var category in formModel) {
            var fields = formModel[category];
            for (var field in fields) {
                availableTags.push({ 
                    category: category,
                    label: field, 
                    value: fields[field] });
            }

        }
        return availableTags;
    }

function setAutoComplete(el) {

        $(el).autocomplete({
            source: getFormModel(),
            create: function () {
                //access to jQuery Autocomplete widget differs depending
                //on some jQuery UI versions - you can also try .data('autocomplete')
                $(this).data('uiAutocomplete')._renderMenu = customRenderMenu;
            }
        });
    }

var customRenderMenu = function (ul, items) {
        var self = this;
        var categoryArr = [];

        function contain(item, array) {
            var contains = false;
            $.each(array, function (index, value) {
                if (item == value) {
                    contains = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return contains;
        }

        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            if (!contain(item.category, categoryArr)) {
                categoryArr.push(item.category);
            }
            console.log(categoryArr);
        });

        $.each(categoryArr, function (index, category) {
            ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-group'>" + category + "</li>");
            $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                if (item.category == category) {
                    self._renderItemData(ul, item);
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: JSON returned data from ajax call (Data at sucess)
[
{"id": 1,"name": "Customer_01"}, 
{"id": 2,"name": "Customer_02"}, 
{"id": 3,"name": "Customer_03"}, 
{"id": 4,"name": "Customer_04"}
]

Textbox "
    <input type="text" id="customerName" name="customerName"
            th:field="*{customer.name}"  />

Need to bind name field of JSON to textbox as auto-completion

Answer (score 0):

Final working code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#customerName").autocomplete({
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "/customer/getByNames",
                    type : "GET",
                    data : {
                        name : $("#customerName").val()
                    },
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(data) {

                        $("#customerName").autocomplete({
                            source : data
                        });
                    },
                    appendTo: "#customerNameResult"

                });
            }

        });
    });
});
```